(Differential) equation formulation for specific problem
I am trying to solve a problem of water discharge through a dam outlet. There are three known dependencies (functions).
The first tells which water elevation corresponds to which volume in the reservoir, and viceversa - let's say $V(H)$, or $H(V)$.
The second tells how the discharge changes with the water elevation, so $q(H)$.
If we assume that the starting volume appears instantly, then these two functions are the only ones required.
In this case, how would you set up an equation that solves for the time required to empty the reservoir from the initial volume $V_{0}$?
Next, if we consider a more realistic situation where the rain causes the volume of water in the reservoir to increase, then the volume is a function of time (known), $V(t)$, and is the third function which should now also be included in the equation.
For the first, simpler problem, I was thinking something like:
$\dfrac{dV}{dH} \dfrac{dH}{dt} = q(H)$
But I haven't gotten much farther than that, and the second problem I hadn't even considered yet.
UPDATE: I have reached a solution by numerical integration which I implemented in python. for the first case there are two equations:
$V_{t+1}=V_{t} - q(H) \cdot \Delta t$
$H_{t+1}=H(V_{t+1})$
With known initial volume, and setting $\Delta t$ to some arbitrary value, I repeated these calculations until the elevation reached a minimum specified value. The sum of all the $\Delta t$ used is the total elapsed time.
For the second case I added a function of increasing volume in the reservoir with rain duration, $V(t_{rain})$. Then the first equation changes to:
$V_{t+1}=V_{t} + \Delta V_{rain,t+1} - q(H) \cdot \Delta t$ ; for $t \leq t_{rain}$
$V_{t+1}=V_{t} - q(H) \cdot \Delta t$ ; for $t > t_{rain}$
and the rest is the same.
I would still like to know how can I express this in the form of a differential equation.

Hint.
Assuming
$$
\cases{
V(h) = a h^2\\
q(h) = k_s \sqrt{h}
}
$$
as $-\dot V(h) = -V_h \dot h = q(h)$ we have  $\dot h = \frac{q(h)}{V_h}$ and then
$$
-\frac{V_h}{q(h)}dh = dt
$$
and after integration we have
$$
h(t) = \frac{3^{2/3} \left(-\frac{k_s (c_0+t)}{a}\right)^{2/3}}{2 \sqrt[3]{2}}
$$
now if at $t=0$ we have $h = h_0$, then $c_0=-\frac{4 a h_0^{3/2}}{3 k_s}$ and finally
$$
h(t) = \frac{\left(4 h_0^{3/2}-\frac{3 k_s t}{a}\right)^{2/3}}{2 \sqrt[3]{2}}
$$
and at $t = \frac{4 a h_0^{3/2}}{3 k_s}$ the reservoir is empty.
NOTE
Concerning to an additional volume $V_a$ due for instance to rain, after comparing the model which considers the rain volume directly at the outflow with the corresponding height (in green) and the model which first increases the height at the reservoir and gets the outflow from this height (in red), the results seems to be the same. Attached a MATHEMATICA script which simulates both cases. To compare, in blue, the height without additional rain. To me, a counter intuitive result.
Clear[a, b, ks, V, Vr, q, h, hk, hk0, dt]
a = 0.1;
b = 0.4;
h0 = 2;
ks = 0.045;
dt = 0.25 ;
tmax = 8.4;
kmax = Floor[tmax/dt];
tr = 0.5;

V[h_] := a h^2
Va[t_] := b Sin[t - tr] (UnitStep[t - tr] - UnitStep[t - Pi - tr])
q[h_] := ks Sqrt[h]
solh0 = NDSolve[{-D[V[h[t]], h[t]] h'[t] == q[h[t]], h[0] == h0}, h, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
solh1 = NDSolve[{-D[V[h[t]], h[t]] h'[t] == q[h[t]] - D[Va[t], t], h[0] == h0}, h, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
gr0  = Plot[{Evaluate[h[t] /. solh0], Evaluate[h[t] /. solh0]}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
gr0a = Plot[{Evaluate[h[t] /. solh1], Evaluate[h[t] /. solh1]}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Green];
t[k_] := dt k
k = 0;
h[k] = h0;

H = {{t[0], h[0]}};
For[k = 0, k < kmax, k++,
 solhk = Quiet@Solve[Va[t[k + 1]] - Va[t[k]] + V[h[k]] == V[hk], hk][[2]];
 hk0 = hk /. solhk;
 soldelta = Quiet@Solve[
 V[hk0] - V[hk0 - delta] == (q[hk0] + q[hk0 - delta])/2 dt, delta][[1]];
 h[k + 1] = hk0 - (delta /. soldelta);
 AppendTo[H, {t[k + 1], h[k + 1]}]
 ]

gr1 = ListPlot[H, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr0, gr0a, gr1, PlotRange -> All]


Attached a python script to simulate the strategy: first fill, after outflow.
a      = 0.1
tr     = 0.5
b      = 0.4
ks     = 0.045
tmax   = 8.4
dt     = 0.25
h      = 200*[0]
h0     = 2
deltai = 0.001
deltas = 0.2
error  = 0.00001
gap    = 2

import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def V(h):
    return a*h**2

def step(t):
    if t > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def t(k):
    return k*dt

def Va(k):
   return  b*m.sin(t(k)-tr)*(step(t(k)-tr)-step(t(k)-m.pi-tr))

def q(h):
    return ks*m.sqrt(h)

def fill_height(k):
    return m.sqrt((Va(k+1) - Va(k) + V(h[k]))/a)

def iteration(hk, deltai, deltas):
    vi = V(hk) - V(hk - deltai) - (q(hk) + q(hk - deltai))*dt/2
    vs = V(hk) - V(hk - deltas) - (q(hk) + q(hk - deltas))*dt/2
    delta = deltas + vi*(deltas - deltai)/(vs -  vi)
    v = V(hk) - V(hk - delta) - (q(hk) + q(hk - delta))*dt/2
    if v < 0:
        vi = v
        deltai = delta
    else:
        vs = v
        deltas = delta        
    return (deltai, vi), (deltas, vs)

def calc2(hk, deltai, deltas):
    vi = 1
    vs = 1
    while min(abs(vi), abs(vs)) > error:
        (deltai, vi),  (deltas, vs) = iteration(hk, deltai, deltas)         
    if abs(vi) < error:
        return deltai
    else:
        return deltas

h[0] = h0

time = [t(0)]
height = [h[0]]
for k in range(m.floor(tmax/dt)-gap):
    hk0 = fill_height(k)
    h[k+1] = hk0 - calc2(hk0, deltai, deltas)
    time.append(t(k+1))
    height.append(h[k+1])

plt.plot(time, height)
plt.show()


How is $\dot{V}(h)=V_{h}\dot{h}$? What does $V_{h}$ represent here?

$\frac{d}{dt}V(h(t))=\frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt} = V_h\dot h$

Then, shouldn't we have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dV}{dh} \dfrac{1}{q(h)} dh = \int dt$, which would give a different result?

$\int \frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{q(h)} = \frac{4 a h^{3/2}}{3 k}$ and $\int dt = t + c$

Please. See a signal tip corrected.

Great, thanks. So how would I implement the additional function of increasing initial volume $V_{rain}(t)$, keeping in mind that the rain does not last through the whole emptying process, so $V_{rain}(t)$ must become $0$ at some point $t=t_{rain}$. I thought something like $-\dfrac{dV}{dh} \dfrac{dh}{dt} = q(h) - \dfrac{dV_{rain}(t)}{dt}$, but I didn't manage to solve it.

The rain can't be converted directly into outflow. The rain should be considered to increase the reservoir volume height simultaneously.  So we have two systems now. One trying to increase the reservoir height and the other outflowing according to this height.

Please. See attached note.

I tried replicating your code in python but I'm getting some errors - doing something wrong. Are you saying that the equation $\dfrac{dV}{dh} \dfrac{dh}{dt} = q(h) - \dfrac{dV_{rain}}{dt}$ should work? Upon more unsuccessful attempts to model this, it occurred to me that $q$ also depends on time, so I though the following should work: $\dfrac{dV}{dh} \dfrac{d^{2}h}{dt^{2}} = \dfrac{dq}{dh} \dfrac{dh}{dt} - \dfrac{d^{2}V_{rain}}{dt^{2}}$, but even with this I'm not getting good results, perhaps there's something wrong with my code. Can you comment on the equations?

So, one other thing I figured... With my functions, when the rain stops, there should be a singularity in the solution (a sharp break in the curve), because up until the rain stops, the volume is increasing, and after the rain stops, the volume should be decreasing. This means I cannot solve it for the whole time interval, but rather I should divide it into the "rain" phase and the "emptying" phase. This way, my code for the first order equation works.

Please. See attached script. I am a novice in python.
